# string with sheet names convert to array formula (code)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a formulated cell containing one string specifying only the  worksheets where I want to modify certain cell under certain conditions:

Notes:
Worksheets "Total", and "Test1" through "Test20" have the same format (I have more worksheets with different names and formats that I don't want to modify at all).

Let's say I want to modify the cell A5 in worksheets "Total", "Test2", "Test7" and "Test12"

A hidden formulated cell (let's say B50) has been formulated to get the following text string: "Array("Total", "Test2", "Test7", "Test12")". I am assigning this value to a variable expecting it to become part of the vba code where Sheets(SheetNamesList).Select can actually be Sheets(Array("Total", "Test2", "Test7", "Test12")).Select

I am getting a Suscript out of range Error and the line [Sheets(SheetNamesList).Select] is highlighted when debugging.

Below is my code. Thank you for your comments

```
Sub Active_to_Installed()

Dim SheetNamesList As String

SheetNamesList = Sheets("Names").Range("B50").Value

If Range("B50").Value = "A" Then

Range("B50").Activate
Sheets(SheetNamesList).Select
ActiveSheet.Activate
Range("A5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "I"

Else

Range("A5").Activate
Sheets(SheetNamesList).Select
ActiveSheet.Activate
Range("A5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "A"

End If
End sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `SheetNamesList` when the error occurs? Check this in the Locals window, or write `?SheetNamesList` in the Immediate window.

Comment: +1 For making me learn something new.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The proper [syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb178404%28v=office.12%29.aspx) is `Sheets(Array("Sheet4", "Sheet5")).Select` but you are using the value of a cell which is most likely a string.  You will need to convert that string to an array of `Sheets`

```
Dim SheetNameArray As Variant
Dim Counter As Integer

SheetNameArray = Split(Worksheets("Names").Range("B50").Value, ",")
Sheets(SheetNameArray).Select
```

I've actually never selected multiple sheets at the same time, and you wouldn't be able to have multiple active sheets so you can't Activate.  You also cannot change the formula of all of them at once here.  So to do that you will need to iterate through the sheets as follows.

```
Dim SheetNameArray As Variant
Dim Counter As Integer

SheetNameArray = Split(Worksheets("Names").Range("B50").Value, ",")
For Each s In SheetNameArray
   Worksheets(s).Range("A5").Formula = "=2+3"
Next s

Sheets(SheetNameArray).Select
```

Note:  You would need to change the value in B50 from `Array("Total", "Test2", "Test7", "Test12")` to `Total, Test2, Test7, Test12`